# Fastest way to shift a Numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

I'm running some simulations that involve repeatedly comparing values in 2D Numpy arrays with their 'neighbours'; eg. the value at indicie location `(y,x)` is compared to the value at indicie location `(y-1,x)` from the same array.

At the moment I am using functions like this:

```
# example of the typical size of the arrays
my_array = np.ndarray((500,500))    

shapey, shapex = my_array.shape
Yshape = (1, shapex)
Yzeros = np.zeros((1, shapex))

def syf(A, E=True):
    if E == True:
        return np.concatenate((A[1:], A[-1].reshape(Yshape)), axis=0)
    else:
        return np.concatenate((A[1:], Yzeros), axis=0)

shifted_array = syf(my_array)

difference_in_y = shifted_array - my_array
```

This has the option to use either the edge values or zeros for comparison at the edge of the array. The functions can also do it in either direction in either axis.

Does anybody have any suggestions for a faster way to do this?
I've tried `np.roll` (much slower) and this:

```
yf = np.ix_(range(shapey)[1:] + [shapey,], range(shapex))
shifted_array = my_array[yf]
```

which is a little slower.

These functions are called ~200 times a second in a program that takes 10 hours to run so any small speedups are more that welcome!

Thanks.

EDIT:

So if the same differentiation method is required every time the shift function is called then Divakars method below seems to offer a minor speedup, however if just a shifted array is required both that method and the one I use above seem to be equal speed.

Comment: I was going to suggest using `scipy.ndimage.convolve1d`, but for this case (very short filter) it's actually ~2x slower than your current approach.

Comment: Looking at the code for `roll`, it generates an index like your `yf`, and then uses `take`.

Comment: Given that the new array is nearly identical to the old I'm surprised there isn't a faster way to do this via indexing that avoids making a new array in memory. Although I guess if `roll` uses `np.ix_` indexing then there probably isn't a faster alternative though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could have the shifting and differentiating both done in a function call like so -

```
def syf1(A, E=True):
    out = np.empty_like(A)
    out[:-1] = A[1:] - A[:-1] # Or np.diff(my_array,axis=0)
    if E == True:
        out[-1] = 0
    else:
        out[-1] = -A[-1]
    return out
```

Thus, the equivalent modified version of `syf` for runtime comparison purposes would be -

```
def syf(A, E=True):
    if E == True:
        return np.concatenate((A[1:], A[-1].reshape(Yshape)), axis=0) - A
    else:
        return np.concatenate((A[1:], Yzeros), axis=0) - A
```

**Runtime tests**

Let's compare the equivalent version of `syf` with the proposed approach on runtime performance for the inputs listed in the question code -

```
In [113]: %timeit syf(my_array)
1000 loops, best of 3: 518 µs per loop

In [114]: %timeit syf1(my_array)
1000 loops, best of 3: 494 µs per loop
```

So, there is *some* improvement there!

Comment: don't forget you can just do `if E:` !!

Comment: @Matthew Thanks for the tip. I would leave it as it is for now, as its a minor thing really and until OP comes back with any feedback. Appreciate that tip nevertheless!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Divakar, I tried a slightly different implementation (my code doesn't always differentiate in that way so just used the 'shift') and the two methods are basically identical speedwise... Odd that they are so similar, I guess thats just the memory access time.

Comment: @Siyh Different way to shift or shift+diff or something else?

Comment: Sometimes its differentiating as above, but is also > or < comparisons, finding the middle value, addition of surrounding values etc..
Shifting is forwards and backwards in x any y

Comment: @Matthew thanks for the tip, I have a feeling that theres loads of little things like that I don't know because of the (very) informal way I've learned to code

Comment: @Siyh If you have found a faster/better solution, it would be nice to  share it with the SO community as your own solution?

Comment: @Siyh I was the same, it's why I started browsing SO. Anyway, you should add an answer or post your own for if someone else comes along who has a similar problem! :)

Comment: Ok will do, thanks for keeping me right on the SO etiquette Divakar, @Matthew