# Fastest way to left-cycle a numpy array (like pop, push for a queue)

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, optimization

With numpy arrays, I want to perform this operation:

- move `x[1],...,x[n-1]` to `x[0],...,x[n-2]` (left shift),
- write a new value in the last index: `x[n-1] = newvalue`.

This is similar to a `pop()`, `push(newvalue)` for a first-in last-out queue (only inverted).

A naive implementation is: `x[:-1] = x[1:]; x[-1] = newvalue`.

Another implementation, using `np.concatenate`, is slower: `np.concatenate((x[1:], np.array(newvalue).reshape(1,)), axis=0)`.

Is there a fastest way to do it?

Comment: Note: this is *not* the same question as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30262736/fastest-way-to-shift-a-numpy-array

Comment: The 'naive' version looks good to me.  Why should there be something faster?  You have to copy values, either to a new array or itself.  When I test your code on `x=np.arange(100000)` I get times like `21.5 µs per loop`.  That looks fast to me.

Comment: There's no way to do this without copying the contents of the array, so I don't think you can do better than the "naive" approach. If this is a bottleneck then you might want to consider using a different datastructure, e.g. a [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque), where the push-and-pop operation does not require a copy and can be done in constant time.

Comment: OK, thanks for your replies, that was my intuition also. I am trying with a deque instead.

Comment: Oh, in fact in the algorithm, not only `X[0]` and `X[1]` are needed, but also a value in the middle of the array, so a `deque` is useless. Sorry!
Thanks anyway for your replies!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

After some experiments, it is clear that:

- copying is required,
- and the fastest and simplest way to do that, for `nparray` (numpy arrays) is a slicing and copying.

So the solution is: `x[:-1] = x[1:]; x[-1] = newvalue`.

Here is a small benchmark:

```
>>> x = np.random.randint(0, 1e6, 10**8); newvalue = -100
>>> %timeit x[:-1] = x[1:]; x[-1] = newvalue
1000 loops, best of 3: 73.6 ms per loop
>>> %timeit np.concatenate((x[1:], np.array(newvalue).reshape(1,)), axis=0) 
1 loop, best of 3: 339 ms per loop
```

But if you don't need to have a fast access to all values in the array, but only the first or last ones, using a [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) is smarter.

Comment: How would the example look when you use deque?

Answer (score 15):

I know I'm late and this question has been satisfactorily answered, but I was just facing something similar for recording a buffer of streaming data.

You mentioned "first-in last-out" which is a stack, but your example demonstrates a queue, so I will share a solution for a queue that does not require copying to enqueue new items. (You *will* eventually need to do one copy using numpy.roll to pass the final array to another function.)

You can use a [circular array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) with a pointer that tracks where the tail is (the place you will be adding new items to the queue).

If you start with this array:

```
x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5]
                               /\
                              tail
```

and you want to drop x[0] and add x[6] you can do this using the originally allocated memory for the array without the need for copy

```
x[6], x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5]
 /\
tail
```

and so on...

```
x[6], x[7], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5]
       /\
      tail
```

Each time you enqueue you move the tail one spot to the right. You can use modulus to make this wrap nicely: `new_tail = (old_tail + 1) % length`.

Finding the head of the queue is always one spot after the tail. This can be found using the same formula: `head = (tail + 1) % length`.

```
            head
             \/
x[6], x[7], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5]
       /\
      tail
```

Here is an example of the class I created for this circular buffer/array:

```python
# benchmark_circular_buffer.py
import numpy as np

# all operations are O(1) and don't require copying the array
# except to_array which has to copy the array and is O(n)
class RecordingQueue1D:
    def __init__(self, object: object, maxlen: int):
        #allocate the memory we need ahead of time
        self.max_length: int = maxlen
        self.queue_tail: int = maxlen - 1
        o_len = len(object)
        if (o_len == maxlen):
            self.rec_queue = np.array(object, dtype=np.int64)
        elif (o_len > maxlen):
            self.rec_queue = np.array(object[o_len-maxlen:], dtype=np.int64)
        else:
            self.rec_queue = np.append(np.array(object, dtype=np.int64), np.zeros(maxlen-o_len, dtype=np.int64))
            self.queue_tail = o_len - 1

    def to_array(self) -> np.array:
        head = (self.queue_tail + 1) % self.max_length
        return np.roll(self.rec_queue, -head) # this will force a copy

    def enqueue(self, new_data: np.array) -> None:
        # move tail pointer forward then insert at the tail of the queue
        # to enforce max length of recording
        self.queue_tail = (self.queue_tail + 1) % self.max_length        
        self.rec_queue[self.queue_tail] = new_data

    def peek(self) -> int:
        queue_head = (self.queue_tail + 1) % self.max_length
        return self.rec_queue[queue_head]

    def replace_item_at(self, index: int, new_value: int):
        loc = (self.queue_tail + 1 + index) % self.max_length
        self.rec_queue[loc] = new_val

    def item_at(self, index: int) -> int:
        # the item we want will be at head + index
        loc = (self.queue_tail + 1 + index) % self.max_length
        return self.rec_queue[loc]

    def __repr__(self):
        return "tail: " + str(self.queue_tail) + "\narray: " + str(self.rec_queue)

    def __str__(self):
        return "tail: " + str(self.queue_tail) + "\narray: " + str(self.rec_queue)
        # return str(self.to_array())


rnd_arr = np.random.randint(0, 1e6, 10**8)
new_val = -100

slice_arr = rnd_arr.copy()
c_buf_arr = RecordingQueue1D(rnd_arr.copy(), len(rnd_arr))

# Test speed for queuing new a new item
# swapping items 100 and 1000
# swapping items 10000 and 100000
def slice_and_copy():
    slice_arr[:-1] = slice_arr[1:]
    slice_arr[-1] = new_val
    old = slice_arr[100]
    slice_arr[100] = slice_arr[1000]
    old = slice_arr[10000]
    slice_arr[10000] = slice_arr[100000]

def circular_buffer():
    c_buf_arr.enqueue(new_val)
    old = c_buf_arr.item_at(100)
    slice_arr[100] = slice_arr[1000]
    old = slice_arr[10000]
    slice_arr[10000] = slice_arr[100000]

# lets add copying the array to a new numpy.array
# this will take O(N) time for the circular buffer because we use numpy.roll()
# which copies the array.
def slice_and_copy_assignemnt():
    slice_and_copy()
    my_throwaway_arr = slice_arr.copy()
    return my_throwaway_arr

def circular_buffer_assignment():
    circular_buffer()
    my_throwaway_arr = c_buf_arr.to_array().copy()
    return my_throwaway_arr


# test using
# python -m timeit -s "import benchmark_circular_buffer as bcb" "bcb.slice_and_copy()"
# python -m timeit -s "import benchmark_circular_buffer as bcb" "bcb.circular_buffer()" 
# python -m timeit -r 5 -n 4 -s "import benchmark_circular_buffer as bcb" "bcb.slice_and_copy_assignemnt()"
# python -m timeit -r 5 -n 4 -s "import benchmark_circular_buffer as bcb" "bcb.circular_buffer_assignment()"
```

When you have to enqueue a lot of items without needing hand off a copy of the array, this a couple magnitudes faster than slicing.

Accessing items and replacing items is O(1). Enqueue and peek are both O(1). Copying the array takes O(n) time.

Benchmarking Results:

```
(thermal_venv) PS X:\win10\repos\thermal> python -m timeit -s "import benchmark_circular_buffer as bcb" "bcb.slice_and_copy()"
10 loops, best of 5: 36.7 msec per loop

(thermal_venv) PS X:\win10\repos\thermal> python -m timeit -s "import benchmark_circular_buffer as bcb" "bcb.circular_buffer()" 
200000 loops, best of 5: 1.04 usec per loop

(thermal_venv) PS X:\win10\repos\thermal> python -m timeit -s "import benchmark_circular_buffer as bcb" "bcb.slice_and_copy_assignemnt()"
2 loops, best of 5: 166 msec per loop

(thermal_venv) PS X:\win10\repos\thermal> python -m timeit -r 5 -n 4 -s "import benchmark_circular_buffer as bcb" "bcb.slice_and_copy_assignemnt()"
4 loops, best of 5: 159 msec per loop

(thermal_venv) PS X:\win10\repos\thermal> python -m timeit -r 5 -n 4 -s "import benchmark_circular_buffer as bcb" "bcb.circular_buffer_assignment()" 
4 loops, best of 5: 511 msec per loop
```

There is a test script and an implementation that handles 2D arrays on [my GitHub here](https://github.com/mcorrig4/python-recording-buffer)

Comment: Could you add a benchmark like the one I did abouve (https://stackoverflow.com/a/42828629/5889533), to compare?

Comment: @Næreen that is a good idea, I'll try that out and add the results.

Comment: @Næreen I made some significant speed improvements to the constructor and added a method to replace items at any spot in the queue. 

It was silly not to do benchmarking and go right to staging this for production. I knew it would be faster, but that was still lazy of me, so I'm glad you gave me the push. 

As I expected, for enqueuing new items the circular buffer is several magnitudes faster than the slice method 1 usec vs 36 msec. There is significantly more overhead if you need to copy the array though, so you would want to choose the appropriate solution for a given scenario.

Comment:  Great job @L-co. Your module is interesting! It requires more code than my naive slice-and-write method I described above (a few yeaors ago) but it's smart and efficient!