# Python array with fixed length but with sequential filling of new values

Tags: python, numpy, queue, deque

Let's us assume we have a variable (shape (1,N,a,b,c)) that is storing numpy arrays with shape (a,b,c). I first want to initialize this variable with zeros

```
import numpy as np
N = 5
a = 20
b = 40
c = 4
storage = np.zeros(1, N, a, b, c)
# collect new arrays
while True:
    values = np.random.random((a, b, c))  # np.array with shape (a, b, c)
    save_values_to_storage(values)
```

The goal of the function save_values_to_storage(values) is to fill up the values from the storage. In the first loop the (1, N,...) values of the storage will be filled with `values`. In the next loop (1, N, ... ) values of the storage will be filled with `values` and the previous values will be moved to (1, N-1, ...). And so forth. If first stored `values` reached the first position (1, 1,...) and new `values` are retrieved and stored the first `values` will get thrown away such that the new `values` are stored at position (1, N,...) and all other values reduced by their position.

> I don't know how I can achieve such a behaviour. It is something like
>   a queue for numpy arrays. So my question is how can I implement the
>   function `save_values_to_storage(values)`?

**Edit**: It seems like `deque` are similar. But I don't know how to use them for numpy array

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved the problem. I am not sure if this is the best way to do this. I appreciate any improvements.

```
import numpy as np
import random

N = 5
a = 20
b = 40
c = 4
inputs = np.zeros((N, a, b, c))
for i in range(0, 10):
    # replace right hand side with method that gets values
    values = np.random.random((a, b, c))
    # expand the dimension to fit to inputs
    values = np.expand_dims(values, axis=0)
    # delete values in first entry of inputs
    inputs = np.delete(inputs, obj=0, axis=0)
    # concatenate inputs and values to a new array
    inputs = np.concatenate([inputs, values], axis=0)
    # for debugging
    # print('shape: {}'.format(inputs.shape))

# expand the dimension with an additional first dimension to achieve (1, N, a, b, c)  # shape.
inputs = np.expand_dims(inputs, axis = 0)
```

Comment: Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42771110/fastest-way-to-left-cycle-a-numpy-array-like-pop-push-for-a-queue? I think it's relevant, even though your data has more dimensions than in that problem.