# Performant circular buffer for frames (ndarrays) of data samples

Tags: python, numpy, streaming, circular-buffer

I'm receiving blocks of audio samples of varying length from a stream, and each block is a 1D ndarray. A block may be received every 50ms or less. I need to keep a buffer of the last 48000 samples

I've tried defining my buffer like this:

```
buffer = np.zeros([48000], dtype=np.float32)
```

Then in my receive block function:

```
buffer = np.concatenate([buffer,input_block])
buffer = np.delete(buffer,slice(0,np.size(input_block))
```

However this is too slow. I understand this is causing a resize and copy of array elements and is not optimal.

I've tried a variety of circular buffer implementations such as [this](http://stadnytskyi.com/circular_buffer_numpy/usage.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66406793/2600531) however they are much slower - I'm not sure why.

Rather than concatenating each new input_block upon receipt I expect it would be more efficient at the point in time where I need to read from my buffer to concatenate a list of past input_blocks. There's a bit of complexity to doing this given the varying size of each block but it should be possible.

Is there another approach I should consider?

Comment: The first package 'appends' each value to the buffer in a [for loop](https://github.com/vstadnytskyi/circular_buffer_numpy/blob/master/circular_buffer_numpy/circular_buffer.py#L73) when it should be done with max 2 slices, [for example](https://github.com/eric-wieser/numpy_ringbuffer/blob/master/numpy_ringbuffer/__init__.py#L115). I tested your approach and could append ~2000 slices of size 5000 to 12000 in 50ms (with a ring buffer ~8500 slices in 50ms). Are you sure this is the bottleneck in the code?

Comment: This is all that the callback (data ready) function in my code does, so was my prime candidate. It is possible there's a bottleneck upstream of my code in the sounddevices package.

Answer (score 1):

Your code makes a new array with the buffer joined to the new block.  Then it makes another array with a same size block removed from the start.  You could reduce the new-array action a bit by first removing the leading block

```
buffer = np.concatenate((buffer[inputbuffer.shape[0]:], inputbuffer))
```

It still makes a new array, but does so only once.  `buffer[inputbuffer.shape[0]:]` is a `view`, a slice of the old.

While we discourage repeated use of `np.concatenate` because it makes a new array, with all the attendant copying, it is at least compiled.  `np.delete` is a general purpose function written in python.  At one level it ends up doing some sort of `concatenate`, but it has to handle generic inputs first.

Another idea would be to make a new buffer, and copy values to it yourself.

```
new_buffer = np.zeros_like(buffer)
n = inputbuffer.shape[0]
new_buffer[:-n] = buffer[n:]
new_buffer[-n:] = inputbuffer
buffer = new_buffer
```

The accepted answer in your second link does something similar

```
x[:-1] = x[1:]; x[-1] = newvalue

buffer[:-n] = buffer[n:]
buffer[-n:] = inputbuffer
```

### timings

```
In [95]: %%timeit buffer = np.zeros(10000); new = np.ones(100)
    ...: buffer= np.concatenate((buffer, new))
    ...: buffer= np.delete(buffer, slice(0,100))
26.7 µs ± 31.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

In [96]: %%timeit buffer = np.zeros(10000); new = np.ones(100)
    ...: buffer= np.concatenate((buffer[100:], new))
10.5 µs ± 14.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

In [97]: %%timeit buffer = np.zeros(10000); new = np.ones(100)
    ...: buffer[:-100]=buffer[100:]
    ...: buffer[-100:]=new
5.09 µs ± 141 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

In [98]: %%timeit buffer = np.zeros(10000); new = np.ones(100)
    ...: buffer1=np.zeros_like(buffer)
    ...: buffer1[:-100]=buffer[100:]
    ...: buffer1[-100:]=new
25.7 µs ± 215 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```